# How to get temporary credentials from AWS cognito to use in AWS transcribe service

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-transcribe

Use Case:-

I have a frontend that is calling Amazon Transcribe service. I'm using s3 as deployment so can't expose the amazon credentials(access_key and secret_key) on front end. So I created a backend endpoint and want to call Cognito service to get temporary credentials that I can pass to front end(even if someone get the creds, it will be only for some time). And then these credentials should be passed to Amazon Transcribe service to get the speech to text.

The thing is I am new to AWS and reading the documentation is creating a lot of confusion for me.

My First question is - Is it possible to get the temporary credentials from Amazon Cognito that can be used in the Amazon Transcribe service?(It is possible, but correct me if I'm wrong.)

Second question - How do I do it? Can you provide some steps and exact resources which I should go through?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Cognito in the equation because you’re researching temporary credentials or because your application users are in a Cognito user pool and you want to perform Transcribe operations as your users’ identities?

Comment: I was just researching how to get temp cred from AWS and I found Cognito.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I generate temporary credentials using Cognito Identity pool for accessing aws services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565073/how-could-i-generate-temporary-credentials-using-cognito-identity-pool-for-acces)

Comment: Also this tutorial maybe helpful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/transcribe-app-browser-script.html

Comment: So, I'm using Amazon live transcribe service, And even if I am able to generate temporary creds and send them to front end, do you think will they work with the transcribe services?

Comment: From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) "You can use temporary security credentials to access most AWS services. For a list of the services that accept temporary security credentials, see [AWS services that work with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html)". Transcribe is listed there as (Yes) for temporary credentials.